# Proving that every element of a coordinate ring can be written uniquely in the form $ P(X) + Q(x)y $

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

> If $ X \subset \mathbb{A}^{2} $ be the algebraic plane curve defined by $ y^{2} - x^{3}. $ Prove that an element of $ k[X] $ can be written uniquely in the form $ P(x) + Q(x)y $ with $ P(x), Q(x) $ polynomials.

Now, $$ k[X] = k[x,y]/\Big(y^{2}-x^{3}\Big) = \Big\lbrace f(x,y)+g(x,y)\Big(y^{2}-x^{3}\Big)\Big\rbrace , $$ for all $ f(x,y),g(x,y) \in k[x,y]. $

I'm unsure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Hint: put $R = k[x]$, and let $h(x, y) \in k[x, y]$. View $k[x, y]$ as $R[y]$, and then apply Euclidean division by the monic polynomial $y^{2}-x^{3} \in R[y]$ to $h(x, y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a module over $k[x,y^2]$, we have $k[x,y]\cong k[x,y^2]\oplus yk[x,y^2]$.  Let $f(x,y)=g(x,y^2)+yh(x,y^2)$.  Then in $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$, $f(x,y)$ has the same image as $g(x,x^3)+yh(x,x^3)$. Now, just note that $g(x,x^3)$ and $h(x,x^3)$ are both polynomials in $x$.

Note, this follows from a mildly souped up version of the fact that for any single variable polynomial $P(x)$, $P(a)-P(b)$ is divisible by $(a-b)$, which in turn follows from the identity $a^n-b^n=(a-b)\displaystyle\sum_{i+j=n-1}a^ib^j$.

Comment: As you note everything follows rather trivially once you know the isomorphism. What I feel is missing from this answer (and the other one) is a proof of this fact. To do this you use the division algorithm, as written by AlexWertheim in a comment.

Comment: @user347489 it doesn’t really require the division algorithm, just the observation that we have a grading on our ring by the degree of y, and we can split it into even and odd components. And this circumvents the need to actually use the division algorithm to find the representative of a given function. But even if you insist on thinking about it in terms of the division algorithm, it is simpler to divide by $y^2$ than by $y^2-x^3$.

Comment: I see, that's a fair point. This approach certainly works, however, writing down a proof like this for more complicated (monic) polynomials in more variables will quickly become messy. On the other hand, the division algorithm argument will run exactly the same. 

Also, depending on your goal you probably want to divide by $y^2-x^3$ because then the residue of the division algorithm will give you the correct class in the quotient ring.

Comment: @user347489 This also gives the correct class in the quotient ring. I agree that using the division algorithm works more generally than this technique, but I also feel that it is important to realize that if you quotient out a ring by an ideal containing $a-b$, then in the quotient ring, $f(a)=f(b)$ and you can do such manipulations without explicitly invoking the division algorithm (which is especially useful when you aren’t working with Euclidean domains).

Comment: agreed ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Well, the standard basis of $K[x,y]/\langle y^2-x^3\rangle$ is given by $1,x,y,xy,x^2,x^3,x^4,\ldots$. Thus each element of the quotient ring has the form $f(x) +yg(x)$.